# Not receiving any new missions in grand theft auto 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I seem to be stuck in a part of the game, no missions are showing on the radar.
I have just finished a mission with a plane and a submarine,

Then in the next heist as Trevor I took masks,a garbage truck,and uniforms.
And now there are no missions to do.

What do I do?

Comment: You might need to swap characters. Try running around on Franklin or Michael for a bit. Trevor might start the new mission by phoning one of them, but that can't happen while you play him.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem myself aswell, The thing i did to fix this was to just walk/drive around with all 3 characters.

When doing this you will usually be contacted by someone that will give you further information (giving you another objective).